# moving custom robot arm to pose goal

Tags: ros-fuerte, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the tutorial at for moving the PR2 arm to a pose goal [(link)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_arm/Tutorials/MoveArmPoseGoal) but I'm having trouble to transitioning this to a custom non-pr2 robot in simulation.

As I understand it the motion plan request must call an action server. From here I'm sort of lost. Can I use the warehouse planner to initialize the robot, and then run a new node to request a new post?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40632/moving-custom-robot-arm-to-pose-goal/) by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your test case is failing when move_arm triggers a planning scene sync via the *setPlanningSceneDiff* service. Maybe inspecting the relevant source code will provide you with more clues. Here's the relevant source files involved, all belonging to the **planning_environment** package:

**collision_models_interface.cpp** contains the *CollisionModelsInterface::syncPlanningSceneCallback(...)*, which is woken up on a sync request. Here's where "Setting planning scene state to NULL" comes from.
If you follow the method's logic, you'll pass through *CollisionModels::setPlanningScene(...)*, in
**collision_models.cpp**, which is where "Incomplete robot state in setPlanningScene" comes from, and end up at *setRobotStateAndComputeTransforms(...)*, in **model_utils.cpp** where the actual problem seems to lie. There's one code path towards the end that returns false, and does not log the failure reason. That's where I believe you should look into.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2012-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) on 2012-08-15**:
Very helpful! I copied the planning_environment package into my workspace and had it output the data causing false to be returned. The string::bool iterator loop is indicating "floating_rot_w" is false, whatever that means. I see it shows up in planning_models so I'll start digging in there.

**Comment by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) on 2012-08-30**:
After doing much back tracing, all I found was that it could not find several of the paramaters when this line is called from any of my programs: get_planning_scene_client.call(planning_scene_req, planning_scene_res). Even just requesting state validity causes the visualizer to crash.

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-08-31**:
exactly the same problem with you mrtc. if you find a solution, plz post here. and i'll try to solve this too.